# How to detect when keyboard height is updated?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, events, keyboard

Is there some way to detect when the user changes assistant menu or how it is called?
I'm successfully updating the view position when keyboard show/hide or change the keyboard type emoji and etc. But I'm unable to find how to get notification when users hides or extends word suggestion area.

Image showing the action that I'm trying to catch https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY3di.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification`?